# NSMatrix access from code; initial layout done in IB

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsmatrix

I am trying to access an NSMatrix object called "matrix" from my code. The object is generated in a NIB, but I keep having problems to access the object that was generated in the interface builder.

If my NSDocument has an **NSMatrix *matrix**, what should I do in the interface builder to link these two? And preferably, to use the initial layout from IB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create an outlet to the matrix. Just create a property in your .h file between the @interface and @end keywords:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSMatrix* myMatrix;
```

and then hold down the ctrl key and drag from 'File Owner' to the matrix object in IB. Make sure you

```
@synthesize myMatrix;
```

in your .m file between the @implementation and @end keywords and you should be able to access all of the properties via dot notation or message calls using:

```
self.myMatrix.somePropertyHere
```

I hope that helps!